# How to return the object of class from the Class self in C#?

Tags: c#

In my C# code, I have a class with properties and a function. Now, I want my function, GetCar to return a object of the class type with values.

I have Error in my code, but can't find it.

```
   public class Car
   {
    public int CarHouseID { set; get; }
    public int CarsInHouse{ set; get; }
    public int CarSold    { set; get; }

    public Car GetCar()
    {
        return Car;
    }
  }
```

Comment: That is not very sensible code.  Instead of obj.GetCar() you'd simply use obj.

Comment: Do you want to call a constructor? e.g. `Car car = new Car();`.

Comment: So you have a _Car instance = new Car()_ and you want to call _Car newInstance = instance.GetCar();_ It makes no much sense.

Comment: You can just copy your existing object to any other variable with Car type. Do some testing like this:
Car Car1 = new Car();
Car1.BuildYear = 2015;
Car Car2 = Car1;
Car2.BuildYear = 2016;
At this point, Car1's build year has also been updated to 2016. That's because both Car1 and Car2 has the same instance of the class. They share the same bit(s) of memory.

Comment: _I have Error in my code, but can't find it._ - you need read exception/error message carefully. StackTrace contains line number in the code which thrown exception. Your code will not even compile so error line will be underlined by red line. Explanation of error will be shown when you hovering this line.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should have a code like below:

```
public Car GetCar()
{
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating objects you have constructors. Unless you define your own constructor on a class, it implicitly comes with a public parameterless constructor (also called public default constructor). Since you have not defined a constructor, you can create a new instance with this call:

```
Car car = new Car();
```

The keyword you are looking for is `new`, which creates an instance by calling its constructor.

If you want to intialize the object first, you can use a method that creates the object and returns it (this seems to bee what you are looking for). This is called a factory method. The problem with the factory method in your example (apart from the fact that there is no constructor call there) is that it is defined on the object. That means you already need an instance to create an instance. That obviously doesn't work. So you have to create the factory method on the class, not on the instance (called a class method). Class methods are declared with marking them `static` in C#:

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarHouseID { set; get; }
    public int CarsInHouse{ set; get; }
    public int CarSold    { set; get; }

    public static Car GetCar()
    {
        return new Car();
    }
}
```